# Signed vs Unsigned operations in C

Tags: c, unsigned

Very simple question:

I have a program doing lots and lots of mathematical computations over ints and long longs. To fit in an extra bit, I made the long longs unsigned, since I only dealt with positive numbers, and could now get a few more values.

Oddly enough, this gave me a 15% performance boost, which I confirmed to be in simply making all the long long's unsigned.

Is this possible? Are mathematical operations really faster with unsigned numbers? I remember reading that there would be no difference, and the compiler automatically picks out the fastest way to go whether signed or unsigned. Is this 15% boost really from making the vars unsigned, or could it be something else affected in my code?

And, if it really is from making the vars unsigned, should I aim to make everything (even ints) unsigned, as I never need negative numbers, and every second is important if I can save it.

Comment: What does the generated assembly code say?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to access or understand it.

Comment: There is generally nothing much to gain from using one extra bit of precision. If you are that close to the border, you will very soon run out of bits again. Could just as well start figuring out a new solution right now.

Answer (score 12):

In some operations, signed integers are faster, in others, unsigned are faster:

- In C, signed integer operations can be assumed not to wrap. The compiler will take advantage of this in loop optimization, for example. Comparisons can be optimized away similarly. (This can also lead to subtle bugs if you don't expect this).
- On the other hand, unsigned integers do not have this assumption. However, not having to deal with a sign is a big advantage for some operations, for example: division. Unsigned division by a constant power of two is a simple shift, but (depending on your rounding rules) there's a conditional off-by-1 for negative numbers.

Personally, I make a habit of only using unsigned integers unless I really, really do have a value which needs to be signed. It's not so much for performance as correctness.

You may see the effect magnified with long long, which (I'm guessing) is 64 bits in your case. The CPU usually doesn't have single instructions do deal with these types (in 32 bit mode), so the slight added complexity for signed operations will be more noticeable.

Comment: `long long` is 64-bit on x86 and x86_64.

Comment: Is that true for all x86_64 ABI implementations?

Comment: AFAIK yes. A few rare 64-bit machines may use 128-bit `long long`, but not x86_64.

Answer (score 2):

On a 32-bit processor, 64-bit integer operations are emulated; using `unsigned` instead of `signed` means the emulation library doesn't have to do extra work to propagate carry bits etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are three cases where a compiler cares whether a variable is signed or unsigned:

1. When the variable is converted to a longer type

   When the comparison operators (greater-than, etc.) are applied

   When overflows might occur

On some machines, conversion of signed variables to longer types requires extra code; on other machines, a conversion may be performed as part of a 'load' or 'move' instruction.

Some machines (mainly small embedded microcontrollers) require more instructions to perform a signed-versus-signed comparison than unsigned-versus-unsigned, but most machines have a full array of both signed and unsigned compare instructions available.

When overflows occur with unsigned types, the compiler may have to add code to ensure that the defined behavior actually occurs.  No such code is required for signed types, because anything that might happen in the absence of such code would be permitted by the standard.

Comment: "When overflows occur with unsigned types, the compiler may have to add code to ensure that the defined behavior actually occurs" - is this relevant for some particular architecture?

Comment: @martinkunev: It was relevant on a Univac ones'-complement machine whose compiler was last updated circa 2004, I think.  The compiler could be configured to process unsigned math with an odd-number modulus, or add code to adjust the result any time there's a wraparound.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't pick if it's going to be unsigned or signed. But, yes, in theory, `unsigned with unsigned` is faster than `signed with signed`. If you really want to slow things down, you'll go with `signed with unsigned`. And even worse: `floats with integers`.

It depends on the processor, of course.